# How to display database fields in seperate textViews

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-studio

I have created a database film app where a user can search for films, the search results then display in a scroll view. The user can then click on a film result which will lead to another activity which will display the full film details (film, actors, directors). How would I retrieve the database fields and display these in separate textViews?

MainActivity:

```
public void search(View v){
    EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    String searchresult = "%" + search.getText().toString() + "%";
    db = new DbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    String[] tblColumns = {"*"};
    String where = "film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?";
    String[] args = {searchresult, searchresult, searchresult, searchresult};
    Cursor results = db.query("FILMTABLE", tblColumns, where, args, null, null, null);
    film(results);
}

public void film (Cursor c){

    c.moveToFirst();
    int titleint = c.getColumnIndex("film");
    int id= c.getColumnIndex("id");
    String title = c.getString(titleint);
    int filmID = c.getInt(id);

    TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txt.setId(filmID);
    txt.setText(title);
    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt.setTextSize(15);
    txt.setClickable(true);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity4.class);
            intent.putExtra("FILM_ID_KEY", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrolLView);
    scrollView.addView(txt);
}
```

MainActivity4:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity4 extends ActionBarActivity {

    String filmId;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        filmId = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.FILM_ID_KEY);
    }
}
```

DbHelper:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String ID = "id";
    private static final String FILM = "film";
    private static final String ACTOR = "actor";
    private static final String ACTOR2 = "actor2";
    private static final String DIRECTOR = "director";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "FILMTABLE";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "filmdatabase3";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final boolean FAVOURITE = false;


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        FILM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        ACTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        ACTOR2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        DIRECTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        FAVOURITE + " BOOLEAN, " +
                        DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

        Cursor countRows = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM FILMTABLE", null);
        countRows.moveToFirst();
        int NumRows = countRows.getInt(0);
        countRows.close();

        if (NumRows == 0) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("film", "Wolf of Wall Street");
            values.put("actor", "Leonardo Dicaprio");
            values.put("actor2", "Jonah Hill");
            values.put("director", "Martin Scorses");
            values.put("description", "Description");
            db.insert("FILMTABLE", null, values);
            values.clear();

            values.put("film", "Captain Philips");
            values.put("actor", "Tom Hanks");
            values.put("actor2", "Catherine Keener");
            values.put("director", "Paul Greengrass");
            values.put("description", "Description");
            db.insert("FILMTABLE", null, values);
            values.clear();

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question lies in the use of ListViews (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). Basically you should create an ArrayAdapter which takes in a List of FilmObjects you retrieve from the database. In this adapter you will define how you want this data shown for each row. When you attach the adapter to the listview Android will take care of the visualization of the each row.

This tutorial will definitely help:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

I would advice to get rid of the seperate Strings that make up a movie but instead make a class that contains all these fields. This allows for much easier data handling.

Comment: Is there no way to do it with a ScrollView?

Comment: @MNT Yes, you could add them dynamically to the scrollview but that wouldn't make sense. The listview component is made for these situations.